# Why my broswer stuck when I switch from vmware to host?

Tags: vmware-workstation

I am currently using VMware 14 pro, and I setup a Linux virtual machine. Everything works fine, but when I switch from VM to host, the host brower stuck for seconds.

How to re-produce:

1. enter vmware. do something .
2. press hot key "ctrl + win + tab",
3. windows switched to a browser of the "host"
4. the browser stuck for 3~20 seconds. the browser got no response for my mouse and keyboard.
5. However, when I move the mouse to the browser tabs position, the browser suddenly got alive! Everything become fine.

The host CPU has 8 core, Memory is 32G, which is enough. ( VMware cost 2 core and 4G ram )

My HOST OS details:

- win7 , 64
- browser: Chrome version 86
- CPU cost is always less than 20%
- Memory used less than 40%

Please give me a clue. thanks !

Comment: You need to install VMware Tools on the Linux Guest. With the Guest Linux machine running, VMware Menu, VM, Install VMware Tools.

Comment: Yes, vmware tool is installed.

Comment: Try setting VMware Hot Keys to default, and then just move the mouse from guest machine to host.  (I use VMware Workstation V16 on Windows 10 Pro).

Answer (score 0):

OK I got the answer.

I think I got the answer 3 months ago, I forgot where this post is ( stackoverflow has many sub domains ... )

the root cause is: the host CPU is not strong enough.

the host CPU is i5 with 4core, 32G memory.

the problems happens when I opened 2 or more virtual machine instances. When I switched from one to another vm, it lagged, or stuck.

This never happen when I do the same thing to my another host machine, which CPU is i7 , with 8 core, 32G. It's quite fluent when I even open 3 vm instances. no lag, no stuck.

so I think the HOST's CPU is quite important, especially when you want to run multiple vm instances at the same time.